# How can I add this style to all pages in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I already have design made in Indesign. Now I just want to add this to the bottom for every page.

There'll be some text (always same) + page number.

[image]

Comment: Look up Master Pages in the help.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but all I see is blank page I don't know if it's correct I have A-Master Page and None in "Pages" when I click on it... It goes to blank page

Comment: You should try *reading* the help pages. :)  Here...  https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html The help pages cover everything you need to know, but you're going to have to read them. It doesn't make a lot of sense to just retype what the help pages state.

Comment: Omg it was so easy. Thank you for that link ! :)

Comment: Scott I've got one questions. I added and it works, but on some pages it just goes behind elements. How to put that master in front?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/master-page-display-on-top-in-indesign *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for helpful answer. Here you can find everything Using master pages in Indesign : https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html

- Thanks to Scott for helping me out :)